# kibana plot percentage of two series of data

Tags: graph, elasticsearch, percentage, kibana

I have two series of data:
 Service A: possible value 0=ok 1=KO
 Service B: possible value 0=ok 1=KO
I would like to plot the avialability of the services in percentage in the same graph.
How could I accomplish this?
I tried with the histogram graph bath what I get is the percentage of count of the 4 events (A:OK,A:KO,B:OK and B:KO)
Thanks